# Cannot destroy object using leap motion fingers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

Good day everyone . I have a little problem with detecting the collision of my fingers to my object . In my first stage my code for destroying object when it collides with my finger is here:

**DetectionCollision.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Leap;
using Leap.Unity;

public class GetFlashLight : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

private HandModel IsHand(Collider other){
    if (other.transform.parent && other.transform.parent.parent && other.transform.parent.parent.GetComponent<HandModel> ()) {
        return other.transform.parent.parent.parent.GetComponent<HandModel> ();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    HandModel hand_model = IsHand (other);
    if (hand_model != null) {
        this.GetComponent<DisableObject> ().enabled = true;
    } else {
        this.GetComponent<DisableObject> ().enabled = false;
    }
}
}
```

**DisableObject.cs**

```
 public GameObject TurnOnFlashLight;
  // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
    TurnOnFlashLight.gameObject.SetActive (true);
 }
```

The problem is when i apply the same code but different c# script (ofcourse)
It didn't work . What do you think the problem is?

[image: Components of my project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to try find if the other collider has a hand:

The 2nd version is put here if you'd prefer to fine tune the searching process or [GetComponentInParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) limitations are a stopper to you.

```
using UnityEngine;

internal class HandModel : MonoBehaviour
{
}

internal class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HandModel TryGetHandVersion1(Collider other)
    {
        return other.GetComponentInParent<HandModel>();
    }

    private HandModel TryGetHandVersion2(Collider other)
    {
        var current = other.transform;
        while (current != null)
        {
            var handModel = current.GetComponent<HandModel>();
            if (handModel != null)
                return handModel;

            current = current.parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var isHand = TryGetHandVersion1(other) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work . But thanks for the response i'll post what i obtain

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using Leap;
using Leap.Unity;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
   FingerModel finger = other.GetComponentInParent<FingerModel>();
    if(finger){
        this.GetComponent<DisableObject> ().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

By doing this i get what i want.